# Getting started: where should I write the program?

Tags: answer-set-programming

so I am required to do an Answer-Set-Programming project, where we should solve some problem and create test cases, using the DLV solver.

According to the specification of the project we need to make the files *G.dl*, *Ch.dl*, and *test.dl* so keeping in mind that I am very new to all of this, here is my question:

what is this .dl file and how do I create one? or better yet:

**Where am I supposed to write all these facts and rules (which I have on paper, by the way) to be able to save the as a .dl file?**

Comment: You can also use an IDE: ASPIDE https://www.mat.unical.it/ricca/aspide/ or SeaLION http://www.sealion.at/ Looking at answer-sets as a text output can be time consuming and slow the testing cycle down, both IDEs parse the output and put into a table. I use ASPIDE presently.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it for my personal project

Answer (score 1):

Those are simple text files, you can write them in any text editor. There is also an online DLV solver at [this webpage](http://dai.fmph.uniba.sk/courses/zui/dlv/).

Comment: that's what I though but when I tried in the command prompt

`dlv.exe test.dl G.dl Ch.dl`

the cmp wrote : can't open input ....

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I downloaded DLV for windows from here:
[link] (http://www.dlvsystem.com/dlv/)

Comment: I managed to run both of my test files (copied code from here: http://www.dbai.tuwien.ac.at/proj/dlv/tutorial/)

Comment: just to make sure: ..... I open a Notepad I type the program and then save it as G.dl? ..... nothing more? .... do I need for example some heading at the beginning of the file like {HTML} ...... {\HTML} or something?

Comment: Yes, it has no headers and such.

Comment: first: thanks for your help and second: I hope you are patient :) but here is what I tried now:.............. I copied this from the link you gave me : `parent(john, james).
parent(james, bill).
grandparent(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), parent(Z, Y)`

and then in cmp in wrote `dlv.exe t.dl.txt` and I got a syntax error on line 3

Comment: You forgot the dot after `parent(Z, Y)`. By the way I am no export of DLV, I haven't even heard of it until now :)

Comment: Thanks, you were a big help for me . it seems you should learn more about DLV, since you solved my "problem" from scratch in half an hour, I think you'll be an expert in no time :))